# Installing IIS with Advanced Installer

Tags: iis, advanced-installer

We have an installer built with Advanced Installer. We are installing IIS from the Windows Feature Bundle. Weird thing is when we run the installer on a fresh Virtual Machine, it works and we can see IIS. However, when client runs it on their computer (they have domain computer) they cannot start the IIS. In fact IIS doesn't show up on the menu. Note: the installer did NOT show any error message. When we looked at the windows features it looks like the IIS should have installed, but can't find it in the menu:
[image: windows features]

Moreover, we have compared the two logs of successful and unsuccessful installation, and surprisingly there were no significant difference that might indicate of any kind of error for the IIS installation.

Here's a screenshot of our advanced installer configuration:

[image: Advanced installer IIS configuration]

Any idea what is going wrong? Or how can we even look for the problem?

Comment: I have never used "Advanced Installer", but I noticed that your "Target Operating Systems" only includes "Windows 10". Are you sure that your customer is using (only) Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, they also use windows 10

Comment: IIS Management Service is an exclusive component of Windows Server, so in no case you see that on Windows 10 machines. To engage the correct audience for further discussion, you should go to https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/ not here, as it is a vendor product.

Comment: @LexLi: we did see that on our Windows 10 machines (home & pro editions). We also asked that on the forum

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether IIS is installed in the system through the command, **press** **"Win + R"** → **enter** **"inetmgr"** → **OK**, if the IIS manager window appears, it means it is installed, otherwise it is not installed.